# Assistance with clarifying what my teacher is asking me to do with multidimentional arrays(c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I am working on a programming assignment for my course. In this program we have to program a shape that we can move around using the mouse. I am using eclipse, which is running on an oracle VM (uses linux mint). Now, my professor added some comments in a given file to point us in the right direction but there is one comment that I cannot understand. That comment is:

> TODO: Write default constructor and constructors to take 16 parameters, a00, a01,..., a10,a11,etc. through a33 to initialize a. 1 parameter x to initialize the diagonal values a[0][0], a[1][1], a[2][2], a[3][3]. All others 0. The default constructor should initialize it the same as passing 1 to initialize a diagonal

I asked him but am still pretty confused and I am not able to get a response quickly enough from the professor. I get the part about constructing an array, which would be like:

```
a[4][4] = {.....};
```

but what I don't get is what the instruction is saying. I was wondering if anyone could look at the instruction and tell me if this is correct based on the instruction(it's probably wrong but this is all that comes to my mind):

```
int a[4][4] = {(0,0), (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4), 
               (0,5), (0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9),
               (1,0), (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),
               (1,5), (1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),
               (2,0), (2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),
               (2,5), (2,6),(2,7),(2,8),(2,9),
               (3,0), (3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),
               (3,5), (3,6),(3,7),(3,8),(3,9),
               (4,0), (4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)
              };
```

I know you could probably do a loop to assign the values without doing it like I did but I just wanted to get a visual since the instruction says:

> initialize the diagonal values a[0][0], a[1][1] etc.

Maybe I am reading into the instruction way too much and am confusing myself when it shouldn't be confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're being asked to write *three* constructors.

The first takes 16 parameters and initializes all 16 elements accordingly.

The second takes 1 parameter, sets the diagonal elements to that value and sets all other elements to zero.

The third takes no parameter and sets the diagonal elements to 1 and all other elements to zero.

Note that there are 16 elements, not 25. Just as an array declared as

```
int a[4];
```

has the **four** elements `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]` and `a[3]` but no element `a[4]`, likewise an array declared as

```
int a[4][4];
```

has 16 elements, and no element `a[0][4]`.

Comment: Yeah I realized I counted badly. I will take a break and try to do it once more. Thanks!

Comment: A professor that instructs students to write a constructor that takes parameter names a00,a01,a02,a03,a10,a11,a12,a13,...a33, is not someone who should be teaching C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It was I who am at fault. I've been looking at another programming assignment as well and have been coding for a couple of hours without a break. It's my fault.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like he wants a 4x4 array with all values except diagonals to be set to 0 in a constructor. This can be done like:

```
int array[4][4];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int u=0;u<4;u++){
        array[i][u] = (i == u ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Or you could just write it all in the constructor:

```
int array[4][4] = {
    {1,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,0,1}
};
```

Comment: wow I was pretty off with what the array would look like haha.  I should take a break. This makes a lot of sense. Thanks! I will try it out after I take my break!